# How to authenticate with Apple SSO (TV Provider) using VideoSubscriberAccount framework

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, single-sign-on, saml

I need to implement authentication scheme using Apple SSO for my application:

1. Check for an signed user in Settings TV Provider
2. Sing in into TV Provider from my app if there is no a signed user
3. Get authentication payload of a signed user from my provider backend with tokens, uuid, etc.

What the main steps to config and implement Apple SSO authentication using `VideoSubscriberAccount` framework because unfortunately there is no much info and samples about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several common steps to implement authentication scheme with Apple SSO:

**1. Config your provisional profile, .entitlements and Info.plist files**

YourApp.entitlements file must have a special key that enables SSO for your app:

```
com.apple.developer.video-subscriber-single-sign-on Boolean YES
```

This entitlement also should be present in your provisional profile e.g.:

[image]

Info.plist must have next key with a message that will be shown to user on first access to the video subscriptions:

```
NSVideoSubscriberAccountUsageDescription String "This app needs access to your TV Provider."
```

**2. Create an account manager instance and implement delegate methods to coordinate access to a subscriber's account.**

```swift
import VideoSubscriberAccount

...

let accountManager = VSAccountManager()
accountManager.delegate = self

...

extension YourController : VSAccountManagerDelegate {
    func accountManager(_ accountManager: VSAccountManager, present viewController: UIViewController) {
        window?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func accountManager(_ accountManager: VSAccountManager, dismiss viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func accountManager(_ accountManager: VSAccountManager, shouldAuthenticateAccountProviderWithIdentifier accountProviderIdentifier: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**3. Determine the state of the application's access to the user's subscription information.**

```swift
accountManager.checkAccessStatus(options: [VSCheckAccessOption.prompt : true]) { status, error in
...
}
```

If the app tries to access to subscription information first time next prompt will be shown:

[image]

**4. Request information about the subscriber's account.**

If access is granted you can make a metadata request to check for a signed user:

```swift
if case .granted = status {         
    let request = VSAccountMetadataRequest()
    request.includeAccountProviderIdentifier = true
    request.isInterruptionAllowed = true
    accountManager.enqueue(request) { metadata, error in
        ...
    }
}
```

The provider selection list and sign-in form will be shown if there is no signed account:

[image]

To skip providers list view you can set supported providers identifiers to the request e.g.:

```swift
request.supportedAccountProviderIdentifiers = ["Hulu"]
```

**5. Second metadata request with required attributes from a identity provider's info endpoint**

If there is no error and signed account is present you should call to your identity provider's info endpoint to obtain required attributes for second metadata call such as:

- `attributeNames`: a list of SAML attributes needed
- `verificationToken`: Base64 encoded signed authentication request from the service provider to the identity provider
- `channelIdentifier`: service provider entity id

And make second request with these parameters:

```swift
request.attributeNames = attributeNames
request.verificationToken = verificationToken
request.channelIdentifier = channelIdentifier
                        
accountManager.enqueue(request) { metadata, error in
    ...
}
```

**6. Request translation of SAML authentication response**

The seconds metadata request responds with Apple's SAML payload that should be sent to your identity provider's translation endpoint then the endpoint parses that element and returns a response that resembles the authentication payload e.g.:

```swift
if let samlPayload = metadata?.samlAttributeQueryResponse {
    let body = [
        ...
        "saml" : samlPayload
    ]
    fetch("https://your.identity.provider/saml/translate", httpBody: body)
}
```

The endpoint should respond with JSON which contains all your authentication data: tokens, uuid etc.